# PlayQueued with different animation states

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Just make any animation and try to use my code on it. What i'm trying to achieve is to play animation using PlayQueued multiple times, each time with different animation state for example to reverse the animation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Animation a;

    void Start () {
        a = animation;
        Invoke("PlayAnimation3",0.3f);
    }

    void PlayAnimation0(){
        //no problem at all...
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
    }

    void PlayAnimation1(){
        //but when you change AnimationState...
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        AnimationState as0 = a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        as0.time = as0.length;
        as0.speed = -1f;
        AnimationState as1 = a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        //... the last AnimationState is the one that counts
        as1.time = 0f;
        as1.speed = 1f;
    }

    void PlayAnimation2(){
        //making a copy of animation does not help
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        AnimationState as0 = a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
        as0.time = as0.length;
        as0.speed = -1f;
        AnimationState as1 = a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimationCopy");
        as1.time = 0f;
        as1.speed = 1f;
    }

    void PlayAnimation3(){
        //it seems duplicated animations have common AnimationState...
        a["simpleAnimationCopy"].time =a["simpleAnimationCopy"].length;
        a["simpleAnimationCopy"].speed =-1f;
        a.Play("simpleAnimation");
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimationCopy");
        a.PlayQueued("simpleAnimation");
    }

    void PlayAnimation4(){
        //any ideas? how to use PlayQueued with different animation states?
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting, strange, I did this only with different animations. Any difference between animations created in Unity3D and imported ones? How do you copy them, script of file system? Did you try different QueueMode parameters?

Comment: animation source, QueueMode, they do not matter, duplicate animation -> CTRL+D or with code, but result is the same